# Get current page type in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to get cuurent page type.

Whene I use this func out of any other function it works !

```
function get_current_page_name(){
    if (is_home() || is_front_page())
        return 'is_home';
    else 
        return 'is_page';
}
```

But whene I use it like this **in home page**

```
function my_function(){
    echo get_current_page_name(); /// returns 'is_page'
}
```

> This functions calls with ajax

Answer (score 0):

I checked it and it seems to work for me.

Can you specify what version of WordPress you are using? Are there any plugins installed? And where exactly do you put this code.

In my test case I added this to my `functions.php` file.

```
function get_current_page_name(){
    if (is_home() || is_front_page())
        return 'is_home';
    else 
        return 'is_page';
}

function my_function(){
    echo get_current_page_name();
}
```

And this to my `index.php` file.

```
<?php
    my_function();
?>
```

This works.

If I will choose home page to some static page in WordPress settings, and put the same but in `page.php` file it still works and returns `is_home`

Comment: You need to provide more specific code you are using. Your code shown here works well. Problem is somewhere else in your code. Please expand your question with your specific use case for this.